# save settings in file

Tags: delphi, settings

I try to write settings into an other delpi project, but it doesn't works 100%.
Not all te data is in the settings.
I use these scripts:

Writing to application:

```
procedure WriteSettings(ServerFile: string; Settings: string);
var
 ResourceHandle: THandle;
 pwServerFile: PWideChar;
begin
 GetMem(pwServerFile, (Length(ServerFile) + 1) * 2);
 try
   StringToWideChar(ServerFile, pwServerFile, Length(ServerFile) * 2);
   ResourceHandle := BeginUpdateResourceW(pwServerFile, False);
   UpdateResourceW(ResourceHandle, MakeIntResourceW(10), 'SETTINGS', 0, @Settings[1], Length(Settings) + 1);
   EndUpdateResourceW(ResourceHandle, False);
 finally
   FreeMem(pwServerFile);
 end;
end;
```

Reading file:

```
function LoadSettings: string;
var
  ResourceLocation: HRSRC;
  ResourceSize: dword;
  ResourceHandle: THandle;
  ResourcePointer: pointer;
begin
  ResourceLocation := FindResource(hInstance, 'SETTINGS', RT_RCDATA);
  ResourceSize := SizeofResource(hInstance, ResourceLocation);
  ResourceHandle := LoadResource(hInstance, ResourceLocation);
  ResourcePointer := LockResource(ResourceHandle);
  if ResourcePointer <> nil then
  begin
    SetLength(Result, ResourceSize - 1);
    CopyMemory(@Result[1], ResourcePointer, ResourceSize);
    FreeResource(ResourceHandle);
  end;
end;
```

For example if i write: "127.0.0.1" then i read: "127."
How can i fix this?

Comment: You are writing only half of the string. You should call the `UpdateResource` function with `cbData` parameter set to size in bytes of the string (you can use e.g. `ByteLength` function for that), not with its length. But your code needs overall review...

Comment: @TLama I would not encourage the use of `ByteLength`. It's a function that receives `string`, so when you pass it an `AnsiString`, it will convert to UTF-16, and then return double the value you expect. So, it works fine for UTF-16 strings, but misleads you in its generality.

Comment: In the last parameter of your `UpdateResourceW` function call use `(Length(Settings) + 1) * SizeOf(Char)` instead of `Length(Settings) + 1`. But take it as a hotfix for your code :-)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan What should I use instead of Byte Length

Comment: Using what `@TLama` suggests is fine

Comment: @DavidHeffernan but when i use that it works but i also get some chinees characters... How can i fix this?

Comment: Chinese characters usually means you put UTF-16 text into a slot that expects ANSI. What happens when you convert to ANSI before writing the text?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The same(I converted the string to ansistring)